# GitLab and SSH/HTTP connection

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I've just set up an Ubuntu 64bit server dedicated to GitLab.

I have successfully installed GitLab and everything seems to work except for the SSH connection using a Git client ( SmartGit ).

I click on "Clone", then I insert the ssh git URL:

```
git@mydomain.test:root/firstproject.git
```

When I click on "Next" it gives me this error:

```
Please check the repository URL.

Could not read from remote repository.: /user/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in 'initialize': getaddrinfo: Name of service not know (SocketError)
from /user/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in 'open'
from /user/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in 'block in connect'
from /user/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in 'timeout'
from /user/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in 'connect'
from /user/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in 'do_start'
from /user/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in 'start'
from /user/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in 'get'
from /user/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in 'allowed?'
from /user/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in 'validate_access'
from /user/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in 'exec'
from /user/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in '<main>'
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

I have tried to generate an SSH key and put it in `/home/git/.ssh/config` but the problem remains the same.
I've even added it as "key" using the Gitlab control panel from web browser.

I have tried to restart GitLab and SSH but it didn't help.
The HTTP method works, but gives me an error if I commint&push lot of files at the same time:

```
The remote end hung up unexpectedly
The remote end hun up unexpectedly
RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 411

Counting objects: 89, done
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Total 88 (delta 12), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

I don't need to fix both problems, I just need to have one of them fully working.

Comment: I have increased the max_file_size of the nginx.conf and now the HTTP method works. If someone knows how to fix the SSH method please adds an answer here.

Comment: Could you please replace the picture by the text version of the error? You can google text, not picture.

Comment: Is it LDAP related as in https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/5415#issuecomment-27027788? And what does `sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production` returns? What are the logs saying?

Comment: No LDAP is not related. The command says `Could not locate Gemfile`. I have cleared auth.log and tried to connect, and it's empty.

Answer (score 2):

From the stack trace, it looks like `gitlab-shell` can't resolve the server's own hostname in DNS to verify repository permissions with GitLab's web API. Try logging into the server and running:

`nslookup mydomain.test`

Where "mydomain.test" is the hostname you're using in the `gitlab_url:` setting in `gitlab.yml`. If you see an error like `** server can't find mydomain.test` in the output, this is your problem.

If so, you can fix this by either:

1. Correcting the DNS configuration of your server by editing [/etc/resolv.conf](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-how-to-setup-as-dns-client.html) so that it can resolve your hostname properly. The DNS servers you need to add depend on your hosting environment; you'll have to talk to someone who administers your network to find the proper values.
2. Changing `gitlab_url` to use `http://localhost/` instead of the externally-routable domain name.
3. Adding an entry to [/etc/hosts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) on your server for `mydomain.test` that points to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: the server can't neither resolve localhost... I've generated a new key with putty key generator, added the public key to the server, loaded the private key when asked in SmartGit, and now it don't gives error but continues asking the ssh key...

Comment: Ok I have added to my DNS server a DNS rule to point to the IP of the Git server, and now the nslookup works correctly using "mydomain.test", but when I try to login it continues to ask me the ssh key...

Comment: Are you being prompted for the password for your SSH key, or for a password for the server (`git@mydomain.test's password:`)? If it's the SSH key password, either the password is mistyped or the key is corrupted somehow; if it's the password for the server, it might be a problem with your `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this isn't a configuration issue, as reported in [issue 3324](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3324#issuecomment-16126888):

> ```
> sudo -u git -H vim /home/git/gitlab-shell/config.yml
> ```
>
> and change:
>
> ```
> gitlab_url: http://yourhost to gitlab_url: http://yourhost/
> ```
>
> Slash at the end is important.